# Unable to start a LVM-Volume after crash of cache-device

Tags: lvm, cache

I'm running a radi6(HDD) setup on a debian 10.7 machine. I'm using this md-device for a LVM VG. I added a SSD as writethrough-Cache. Unfortunately my bash-history doesnt' contain the commands of the build.
However - after some days of my working Setup the SSD died including the cache-devices. After the installation of the new debian, because root was on the SSD as well, I was not able to start the LVM-Volume. I got an error Message like

`Couldn't find device with uuid`

I was trying `vgreduce --removemissing`  - the result was a complain that the machine is not able to start the cache.

I was searching for similar problems and find a answer - adding an new PV and create new LV's with the missing UUID. I did that and the `Couldn't find device with uuid`  gone.

But I'm not able to start the LVM-Volume.

```bsh
root@fileserver:~#lvchange -ay raid6-4T

Check of pool raid6-4T/r6_4T_files_cache failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
```

```bsh
root@fileserver:~# lvs -a --units m
  LV                        VG       Attr       LSize        Pool                Origin              Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvm-var                   raid6-4T Cri---C---    35944,00m [lvm-var_cache]     [lvm-var_corig]                                            
  [lvm-var_cache]           raid6-4T Cwi---C---     5036,00m                                                                                
  [lvm-var_cache_cdata]     raid6-4T Cwi-------     5036,00m                                                                                
  [lvm-var_cache_cmeta]     raid6-4T ewi-------       40,00m                                                                                
  [lvm-var_corig]           raid6-4T owi---C---    35944,00m                                                                                
  [lvol0_pmspare]           raid6-4T ewi-------      852,00m                                                                                
  r6_4T_files               raid6-4T Cwi---C--- 15225324,00m [r6_4T_files_cache] [r6_4T_files_corig]                                        
  [r6_4T_files_cache]       raid6-4T Cwi---C---    34172,00m                                                                                
  [r6_4T_files_cache_cdata] raid6-4T Cwi-------    34172,00m                                                                                
  [r6_4T_files_cache_cmeta] raid6-4T ewi-------      852,00m                                                                                
  [r6_4T_files_corig]       raid6-4T owi---C--- 15225324,00m
```

I tried to repair:

```bsh
 root@fileserver:~# lvconvert --repair /dev/raid6-4T/r6_4T_files_cache
bad checksum in superblock
  Repair of cache metadata volume of cache raid6-4T/r6_4T_files_cache failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
```

```bsh
root@fileserver:~# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/raid6-4T/r6_4T_files
  LV Name                r6_4T_files
  VG Name                raid6-4T
  LV UUID                P1oxae-VTkp-mu6p-8a5z-un2R-pXz9-YjakTI
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time fileserver, 2019-08-08 15:57:56 +0200
  LV Cache pool name     r6_4T_files_cache
  LV Cache origin name   r6_4T_files_corig
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                14,52 TiB
  Current LE             3806331
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto  
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/raid6-4T/lvm-var
  LV Name                lvm-var
  VG Name                raid6-4T
  LV UUID                RNqJF7-FLxx-5WvX-6ceH-NtHl-hvqd-Fus5A5
  LV Write Access        read only
  LV Creation host, time fileserver, 2020-12-13 14:45:51 +0100
  LV Cache pool name     lvm-var_cache
  LV Cache origin name   lvm-var_corig
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                35,10 GiB
  Current LE             8986
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto`
```

```bsh
root@fileserver:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               raid6-4T
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  81
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               14,59 TiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              3825555
  Alloc PE / Size       3825555 / 14,59 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               88lUal-4tQX-CEcf-ZNZe-rdGv-3B2x-4ZCDrp
```

How can I paste a code with line-breaks? - I know this thread is not good formated.

The goal is to minimum mount the filesystem on the LV - when the datas are saved I could recreate the setup. In best case we bring the setup back to life.

I hope all necessary informations are included - otherwise please complain!

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reactivate the LVM-Volumes, but I was able to get read access to the data.

```
root@fileserver:~# lvchange -ay raid6-4T/r6_4T_files_corig --activationmode partial
  PARTIAL MODE. Incomplete logical volumes will be processed.
Do you want to activate component LV in read-only mode? [y/n]: y
  Allowing activation of component LV.
  Couldn't find device with uuid tOkG3t-aWGl-4PfO-DI3O-TMoG-ia1z-p4UQgP.
  Couldn't find device with uuid qmDOrk-0SRI-9Z1S-PzgI-GRI8-xLrP-kC5LHd.

root@fileserver:~# mount -o noload -r /dev/mapper/raid6--4T-r6_4T_files_corig /media/data/

root@fileserver:~# lvchange -ay raid6-4T/lvm-var_corig --activationmode partial
  PARTIAL MODE. Incomplete logical volumes will be processed.
Do you want to activate component LV in read-only mode? [y/n]: y
  Allowing activation of component LV.
  Couldn't find device with uuid tOkG3t-aWGl-4PfO-DI3O-TMoG-ia1z-p4UQgP.
  Couldn't find device with uuid qmDOrk-0SRI-9Z1S-PzgI-GRI8-xLrP-kC5LHd.

root@fileserver:~# mount -o noload -r /dev/mapper/raid6--4T-lvm--var_corig /media/var/
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today (cache SSD died) but ended up running `vgreduce --removemissing --force` which removed the associated logical volumes as well! After a quick panic, I tried to use vgcfgrestore to restore the LVs from the archived LVM configurations, but this also kept failing due to the missing physical volume.

The fix for me was to edit the archived LVM configuration (in /etc/lvm/archive/vgname.vg) and remove any references to the defective PV and the cache devices/volumes.

In that file, you will find references to your PVs (including the defective one) and your LVs (let's call one 'lvname' in this example). The LV reference will have a single segment of type "cache". You will also find an LV called 'lvname_corig' with multiple segments on your data PVs, indicating where the non-cached data is stored, and more LVs for the cache metadata etc.

My process to fix this was:

1. Back up the original VG config file.
2. Copy the 'id' and 'state' lines from lvname, then find the volume called lvname_corig and paste them there (comment out the id and state lines in that block).
3. Delete the lvname block.
4. Delete any related volume blocks for the cache (cachedatalvname_cpool,
   cachedatalvname_cpool_cmeta, cachedatalvname_cpool_cdata).
5. Rename the lvname_corig block to just lvname.
6. Delete any other volumes that reference the defective PV (In my case there was a lvol0_pmspare volume).
7. Delete the reference to the defective PV (in my case this was a block called 'pv3').

Once you've done all these edits, use `vgcfgrestore -f filename vgname` to restore your VG/LV configuration without the defective cache PV or any related cache volumes.